# Unable to get a static IP to work on Ubuntu 14.04 with a Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: 14.04, raspberrypi, static-ip

I'm having trouble with setting a static IP address on my Rasp Pi. I've tried out a lot of different solutions but none have worked thus far.

Here's my current setup:
    nano /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces (5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown (8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.115
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.115 192.168.1.1
```

Heres are the ifconfig results:

```
eth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:c1:f2:e3
         inet addr:192.168.1.115  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
         inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fec1:f2e3/64 Scope:Link
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
         RX packets:48119 errors:0 dropped:33728 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:3015 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:6147740 (6.1 MB)  TX bytes:398394 (398.3 KB)

lo       Link encap:Local Loopback
         inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
         inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
         UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
         RX packets:178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
         RX bytes:13704 (13.7 KB)  TX bytes:13704 (13.7 KB)
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text and apply code formatting.

Comment: why did you setup your computer and gateway as a nameserver? i think the problem is caused by the nameserver setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misconfiguring your DNS servers here.  Only in very very specialized cases are you going to set your DNS servers to be your computer and the default gateway.

If you don't know what DNS servers exist on your environment then just use Google name servers:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Once done reboot the RPi - it should then accept the new network settings... or it won't in which case we have to do more work to fix.

I also suggest using `allow-hotplug eth0` instead of `auto eth0` in the off chance you may need to boot without an Ethernet connection.  This will prevent a boot hang up if networking fails to configure.